# How to deploy a react app with json-server without any server.js file?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, json-server

here's my repo https://github.com/asujsi/user-list
I want to deploy it to heroku, I tried and failed.
Should I deploy both db.json and react project in separate repo please help

Comment: What error did you get? Any log? Provide more detail

Comment: https://github.com/asujsi/user-list/commits/master if you see the heroku commits on 18 march after this commit the app was crashing on the link https://tasktracker007.herokuapp.com/ (like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMV1N.png) sorry that the error will not be shown as after that I also tried to connect express with the json-server which I am still figuring around. It was perfectly working fine locally so no error was there.

Comment: Only you can see the logs as you are the owner